# FB async call triggered multiple times, but excecutes only once

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, promise

I'm having trouble with the Ionic v2 Facebook plugin, using `.api()`. I trigger it a few times, the first gets results, but the other are seemingly ignored:

```
Facebook.api("/"+ validAlbumId_A +"/picture?access_token="+validToken+'&redirect=false', []).then(
    (response) => {  console.log(response.data.url);  }, // <-- this gets logged
    (error)    => {  console.log("oh noh"); }
);
Facebook.api("/"+ validAlbumId_B +"/picture?access_token="+validToken+'&redirect=false', []).then(
    (response) => {  console.log(response.data.url);  },
    (error)    => {  console.log("oh noh"); }
);
Facebook.api("/"+ validAlbumId_C +"/picture?access_token="+validToken+'&redirect=false', []).then(
    (response) => {  console.log(response.data.url);  },
    (error)    => {  console.log("oh noh"); }
);
```

**Result:** One response url (the first one).

However, if I change the code and make the FB calls sequential (wait for the previous to complete), I get all the results.

Can anyone explain why I can't just run them in parallel? Why must I wait?

Comment: How can it call 8 times if you only call it once? There's no loop in your code.

Comment: You're right, I don't loop. I call them recursively, please see the `if` on the 4the line of the codeblock :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't pay enough attention! I can't answer why the callback only gets called once but wouldn't it make more sense to let `getCoverImages()` return a promise that you push into an array and then await them all?

Comment: yes it would, but the core problem remains. I can only run one `facebook.api()` at a time, so multiple promises (as my code was first) doesn't work.

Comment: where does "someAlbumId" come from? what is the initial index and max? right now this code does not make a lot of sense, to be honest. please add more information.

Comment: I've added the result of the log, I've removed the actual tokens from the code, the tokens work (otherwise Ther frist call wouldn't work either)

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to _achieve_ here? Your code as shown just seems to make the exact same API call each time, the parameters used don’t change.

Comment: And someone with the right priveledges, maybe clear the comments as they're no longer relevant and confusing now?